# A cyclic vector for the Dirichlet Laplacian on interval.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, self-adjoint-operators

While revisiting the notion of a *cyclic vector* for a self-adjoint operator (see, e.g., Schmuedgen, *Unbounded Self-adjoint Operators on Hilbert space*, Section 5.4), I got stuck when I tried to figure out a couple of concrete examples on 'everyday life' operators.

Consider the Dirichlet Laplacian on an interval, say, the operator $T=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ acting on the Hilbert space $L^2(0,1)$ with domain (of self-adjointness) $D(T)=\{f\in H^2(0,1)\,|\,f(0)=f(1)=0\}$.

QUESTION A. Does $T$ admit a cyclic vector? In other words (Schmuedgen, Definition 5.1), is there a function $\varphi\in D(T)$ (as well as $\varphi\in D(T^n)$ for any positive integer $n$) such that the span of $\varphi,T\varphi,T^2\varphi,\dots$ is actually *dense* in $L^2(0,1)$? I understand that this is tantamount as asking whether $T$ has *simple spectrum* (Schmuedgen, Definition 5.1).

QUESTION B. Does $T$ admit a cyclic vector $\varphi$ that belongs to $C^\infty[0,1]$ *and* vanishes, together with all its derivatives, at $x=0$ and $x=1$ ?

(*My motivation:* it is easy to decide the existence of cyclic vectors for operators in multiplication form, I was trying to practice with differential operators instead.)

Comment: B: "functions that are compactly supported inside $(0,1)$". Wouldn't they and all their derivatives be $0$ in a neighbourhood of an endpoint?

Comment: Do you mean $C_c^{\infty}[0,1]$ ?

Comment: You're right, I clarified the meaning of my "question B" by editing it. I am wondering whether a cyclic vector $\varphi$ can be found for $T$ such that $\varphi$ is smooth and vanishes at $x=0$ and $x=1$ together with all its higher-order derivatives.

Comment: My only thought is to Fourier transform into multiplication form and ask whether there  are cyclic vectors, and then whether any of these correspond to smooth functions. [Google Books "preview" of your reference.](https://books.google.ca/books?id=2d7zZ5_9izEC&pg=PA99&dq=Unbounded+Self-adjoint+Operators+on+Hilbert+space+%22cyclic+vector%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjfopf2w-XlAhVFJzQIHYypBWEQ6AEIOTAC#v=onepage&q=Unbounded%20Self-adjoint%20Operators%20on%20Hilbert%20space%20%22cyclic%20vector%22&f=false)

Comment: It looks like this article might be relevant: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82054694.pdf (see Proposition 3). The authors show that a diagonal operator (such as the Laplacian when represented in the basis of its eigenfunctions) is cyclic iff it does not have eigenvalues with multiplicity >1. Also, sufficiently "generic" vectors will be cyclic (see Proposition 2).